# Autocomplete select error while select the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got data from my database and i can see on my textfield , but when i try to click on one of the value the value is not coming on textbox field.

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#txt_cname").autocomplete({
        source: 'edit_autocomplete.php',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, data) {
            $("#agent_id").val(data.item.aname)
        }});
});
```

Comment: Could you post some HTML, containing #txt_cname and #agent_id?

Answer (score 1):

the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) should look for a value, not a name:

```
$("#agent_id").val(data.item.value);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but my issue is not related to that , i can see all my value in a text field name txt_cname and when i select a value from the list it is disappeared from text field

Comment: what `textfield` are you referring to, `#agent_id`?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#txt_cname").autocomplete({
  source:'edit_autocomplete.php',
  minLength:1});
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<input type="text" name="txt_cname" id="txt_cname" />

Comment: dude, I still don't see `#agent_id`